# Joguei esse estilo no drawable para ter borda no meu EditText, funcionou mas não entendi nada dele

Tags: android

Eu copiei na net esse código para dar uma borda mas não entendo pq tem três itens, alguém me ajuda?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- most important is order of layers -->
    <!-- Bottom right side 2dp Shadow -->
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#363636" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Bottom 2dp Shadow -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#363636" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- White Top color -->
    <item android:bottom="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" android:left="3dp" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Parece que no android nao há conceito de border. Entao eles sugeriram para voce criar retangulos para ter o mesmo efeito. Parece que o border também tem cores diferentes e eles acabaram por criar 1 rectangulo para cada cor.

Comment: @ramaral Voce deixou um item repetido sem querer

Comment: @BrunoCosta não foi engano não. O xml não estava formatado devidamente, por isso só apareciam dois. O que me chamou à atenção para isso foi o AP referir 3 itens e só aparecerem 2.

Comment: @ramaral certo irei apagar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem razão em questionar o porquê de ter 3 itens.

De facto um deles está a mais.

Uma [layer-list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList), tal como o nome sugere, é uma lista de camadas, neste caso de *Drawables*.
Cada um dos *Drawables* é desenhado sobre o anterior.

Desenhar duas coisa iguais, uma em cima da outra, é o mesmo que desenhar apenas uma.
Pode eliminar um dos dois primeiros que o comportamento é mantido.

O efeito de "borda" é conseguido sobrepondo um rectângulo branco sobre um de cor `#363636`. Como o rectângulo branco é mais pequeno, deixa visível em toda a sua periferia uma porção de **3dp** do outro.